# How to add twitter widget id dynamically in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter

I have trouble in twitter widget id dynamically adding.when i add username and widget id in backend the data will added dynamically through the anchor tag..

```
NavigateUrl='https://twitter.com/rajeeshmenoth' CssClass="twitter-timeline" data-widget-id="64643131786644">Tweets by @rajeeshmenoth
```

username added successfully.widget id is not a property of anchor tag.how it assign in this same anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<a href="javascript:void(showTwitter('twitter-wjs',
  {width:220,height:300,color:'#ff0000',theme:'dark',element:'body'}))">LOAD SMALL</a>
```

[Reference](http://tappetyclick.com/blog/2012/12/20/how-dynamically-resize-new-twitter-widget#.U8ZpKvmSwpQ)

[Working](http://tappetyclick.com/sites/default/files/sites/default/files/media/twitter.htm)